# fpdf + php how to insert an image in a cell on right side in pdf document?

Tags: php, fpdf

```
$image1 = "call.png";
$pdf->Cell(0,8,$pdf->Image($image1, $pdf->GetX()+2, $pdf->GetY()+2, 20.78),0,0,'',true);
```

I tried the above code to insert an image in a cell of pdf document. i want to align this image on right side in cell.

Comment: You'll need to retrieve the X_max of your document, substract your image's width from it then insert it in the X you got from the substraction ?

Answer (score 7):

In FPDF there are internal variables `w` and `h` for width and height, respectively. However, these are represented in the user units. By default, this is millimeters. Images are always going to be presented in pixels, which can cause a problem. That said, FPDF also tracks `wPt` and `hPt`, which give you the dimensions in a manner that can be very easily compared with to pixel units. Finally, there is `k`, which is a scale unit that can be used to convert from the user units to pixels.

We will do the following:

- Get the image dimensions with [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)
- Get the page dimensions in pixels with `$pdf->w`
- Calculate the total page width and subtract the image width to get the left padding we need
- Use `$pdf->k` to convert the left padding from pixels to user units
- Print an empty boundary cell left of the image with `$pdf->Cell`
- Print the image with `$pdf->Image`

We will *not* put the image in a cell. Don't do this. Cells weren't built for images, only for strings. You will not get intended results if you attempt this method. Instead, opt for the method above. Code as such:

```
//  Get image dimensions
$size = getimagesize('img.png');

if( $size===false )
    die('Image does not exist.');

$wImg = $size[0];
$hImg = $size[1];

//  Get PDF dimensions
$wPdf = $pdf->wPt;
$hPdf = $pdf->hPt;

//  Calculate width necessary for the cell
$width  = $wPdf - $wImg;

if( $width<0 )
{
    error_log('Image is larger than page we\'re trying to print on.');
    $width = 0;
}

//  Convert pixel units to user units
$width  /= $pdf->k;
$height /= $pdf->k;

//  Print a boundary cell
$pdf->Cell($width,$height);

//  Print image
$pdf->Image('img.png');

//  Force a new line
$pdf->Ln();
```

I would recommend putting this into a function or something of the like if you plan to use it a lot. Note that this only works for *right* alignment. You will do a similar method with different calculations for *center* alignment. The boundaries to the left and right on the page are defined by FPDF and can be set in the constructor with [`SetMargins`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setmargins.htm)

Comment: I removed this line `$hPdf = $pdf->hPt;` and added this line `$height = $hImg;` after `$width  = $wPdf - $wImg;` to stop a variable undefined error. Once I did that, it worked a treat, thanks.

Comment: This is the error I get: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access protected property FPDF::$wPt